# C++ - Undeclared Identifier / Left of 'FUNCTION' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++, struct, direct3d

I've searched all the day about this but none of the answers seem to help me fix the errors...

I'm currently doing a DLL in C++ that hooks the EndScene of a game, and gets `viewmatrix` and translate to screen...
All the code is fine, but seems like some variable is messing up everything...

I'm getting those errors

> Error 1: 'LocalPlayer': undeclared identifier
>
> Error 2:
>       left of '.flMatrix' must have class/struct/union
>
> Error 3:
>       left of '.WorldToScreenMatrix' must have class/struct/union

Here is the `WorldToScreen` function:

```
    bool WorldToScreen(float * from, float * to)
{
    HWND atual = GetActiveWindow();
    RECT m_Rect;
    GetWindowRect(atual, &m_Rect);

    float w = 0.0f;

    to[0] = LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[0][0] * from[0] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[0][1] * from[1] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[0][2] * from[2] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[0][3];
    to[1] = LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[1][0] * from[0] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[1][1] * from[1] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[1][2] * from[2] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[1][3];
    w = LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[3][0] * from[0] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[3][1] * from[1] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[3][2] * from[2] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[3][3];

    if (w < 0.01f)
        return false;

    float invw = 1.0f / w;
    to[0] *= invw;
    to[1] *= invw;

    int width = (int)(m_Rect.right - m_Rect.left);
    int height = (int)(m_Rect.bottom - m_Rect.top);

    float x = width / 2;
    float y = height / 2;

    x += 0.5 * to[0] * width + 0.5;
    y -= 0.5 * to[1] * height + 0.5;

    to[0] = x + m_Rect.left;
    to[1] = y + m_Rect.top;

    return true;
}
```

The error is on this lines:

```
to[0] = LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[0][0] * from[0] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[0][1] * from[1] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[0][2] * from[2] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[0][3];
    to[1] = LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[1][0] * from[0] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[1][1] * from[1] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[1][2] * from[2] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[1][3];
    w = LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[3][0] * from[0] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[3][1] * from[1] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[3][2] * from[2] + LocalPlayer.WorldToScreenMatrix.flMatrix[3][3];
```

The LocalPlayer struct is:

```
struct LocalPlayer
{
    DWORD Local;
    int Team;
    int Health;
    WorldToScreenMatrix_t WorldToScreenMatrix;
    float* Position;
    int Flags;
    int CrossHair;
    void Read()
    {
        Local = *(DWORD*)(dwClient + dwLocalPlayer);
        if (Local != NULL)
        {
            Team = *(int*)(Local + dwTeam);
            Position = (float*)(Local + dwOrigin);
            Health = *(int*)(Local + dwHealth);
            CrossHair = *(int*)(Local + dwCrossHairID);
            WorldToScreenMatrix = *(WorldToScreenMatrix_t*)(dwEngine + dw_vMatrix);
        }
    }
}LocalPlayer;
```

the flmatrix is on:

```
typedef struct
{
    float flMatrix[4][4];
}WorldToScreenMatrix_t;
```

Where is causing the error?

Comment: You do include the header file where `LocalPlayer` is defined? And do note that defining variables in header files is usually a bad idea.

Comment: And don't give a type and a variable the same name, it confuses everyone.

Comment: It looks like you're expecting LocalPlayer to be an instance of that struct, but that's the name of the struct itself.

Comment: @tadman See the comment by Mat. The OP does `struct LocalPlayer { ... } LocalPlayer;`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's what I mean and as you point out that's nothing but trouble of the first order.

Comment: Hello, i've tried to get this function where the localplayer is, the localplayer is in menu.h and this function is in draw.h, i know that both places it should work, but the error on both is the same, i've tried to rename the LocalPlayer at the end of the struct and it gives me the same error,i think the problem is anything in float* position or the WorldToScreenMatrix declaration.

Comment: You have to include `LocalPlayer` defined header(.h) file or re-define `struct LocalPlayer{}`.

Comment: @A.Godnov I've tried to do this already, the error remains the same

Comment: So you haven't succeeded in doing so yet. Keep trying.

Comment: lol, i'm trying all the day and searching around, none of the solutions seems to fix it x.x

Comment: Is LocalPlayer in a header? Certainly looks like an include issue... Also avoid globals, and if you really can't..., be sure to use `extern LocalPlayer localplayer`  and a definition in a .cpp else you will get multiple copies that are not shared.